# BigQuery: Return the first value in a group by situation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following problem - I have an AB Test table where each user is assigned an experiment at some time `t`. Experiments can go up and down all the time. Although an experiments which goes down usually goes down for good.

Now I want to calculate different user metrics alongside of getting the experiment that was assigned to the user at when it was first seen at the table

```
| user | experiment | time | is_click
| u1.  | e1         | t1.  |    0
| u1.  | e2         | t2.  |    0
| u2.  | e2         | t3.  |    1
| u2.  | e2         | t4.  |    1
```

For the above I want to calculate the following:

```
u1, e1, ctr_u1, ...
u2, e2, ctr_u2, ...
```

and I have an working but awfully slow query that works on relatively small amount of data, but fails to run on high scale (6+ hours run):

```
select user_id, 
       array_Agg(experiment ignore nulls order by time asc limit 1)[OFFSET(0)] first_experiment,
from user_experiment
group by user_id
```

I looked at `FIRST_VALUE` but it doesn't seem to work if `experiment` is not part of the group by. I wonder whether there's more efficient way of getting this information?

Thanks.

Comment: Why this got a minus? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Your query would return the earliest experiment assigned to each user since the group by is on user_id. Do you want that or do you want the users who were assigned the earliest instance of each experiment? In the latter case group by should be on the experiment as you mentioned.